# Sitecore ContentSearch results order is not same as raw Solr search results

Tags: content-search, solr

Sitecore ContentSearch is not providing result in the same order like Solr query does.

`http://localhost:8983/solr/sitecore_web_index/select?indent=on&q=_content:testorder&wt=json`

we are getting result in the following order

1. x
2. y
3. z

but when we use ContentSearch API we are getting results in different order.

```
var results = Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext().GetQueryable<Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem>().Where(x => x.Content.Contains("testorder")
```

when we iterate the list, we get different order:

1. y
2. x
3. z

How can I get results from ContentSearch in the same order as Solr?

Comment: What is the raw query that Sitecore is executing when you run that `ContentSearch` code in your question? (You can find this by checking the Search logs in your data folder: `/data/logs/Search.log.DDDDDDDD.TTTTTT.txt`.) My guess is that it's a different underlying query which causes the difference in result order.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  x.Content.Contains("testorder") form query like q=_content:*testorder* . to get q=_content:testorder, we have to use x.Content=="testorder"

Comment: also sitecore linqtosolr support equal method

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to troubleshoot issues like this is to review the search logs to see what query Sitecore is building behind the scenes:

1. Execute your code that performs the search
2. Load the latest search log file (located in your data folder: `/data/logs/Search.log.DDDDDDDD.TTTTTT.txt`)
3. Find your search and see how it was constructed

Based on your code and subsequent comment, it looks like the solution to your issue is to change your `ContentSearch` code from `x.Content.Contains("testorder")` to

```
x.Content == "testorder"
```

Answer (score 0):

`x.Content.Contains("testorder")` forms the Solr query `q=_content:*testorder*`

To get `q=_content:testorder`, we have to use `x.Content == "testorder"`